# Remove extra space in Outlook email

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add text in grey box in my email.
For some reason only on outlook desktop version, it is throwing an extra space just on the top.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="%%=v(@paragraphGreyBoxR)=%%background:#F0F1F2;border-radius:5px;color:#000000;border-collapse:collapse;padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;mso-padding-alt: 15px 15px 15px 15px;">Can't attach the itemized invoice or proof of purchase? You can also fax us or get in touch by postal mail. Simply send a copy of this email, the itemized invoice, and your proof of purchase to (000)000-0000 or</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: it is not a trick question because I did not add any empty line. It works fine in all the other email clients, just in case of outlook it does not

Comment: Why the DIV - it seems useless here

Comment: It is an existing code in production. I need to reuse it. The new mock has padding of 15 on all sides. When I try to add that, this new issue came up.I tried removing div and it did not work.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? You know if the code is rendered in two sets, the client will try to fix illegal HTML

Comment: I have added the html to the description

Comment: If you have a way to easily duplicate the issue in outlook I would suggest removing that custom styling one at a time and see if that is whats causing the issue. I am referring to this: `%%=v(@paragraphGreyBoxR)=%%background:#F0F1F2;`